# PowerBI Row Level Security for Report

Tags: powerbi, row-level-security

I have followed the [PowerBI Tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCKaGCu2zsF8Fsr0hreKCG8A) on YouTube for Static Row Level Security, creating a simple dataset that includes a "ClientName".

In **Power BI Desktop** - I added two roles, which filter the data down to two different sets of client data, shown below.

[image: Adding Roles]

In **Power BI Service** - I have added two different users, one to each of the two roles and tested. Everything works as expected, when selecting either of the two roles, when entering the email address of either of the users and I get expectedly rejected when I enter a random email address.

[image: Adding Rsers to Roles]

So, everything up to this point appears to have worked as I would expect.

**I publish the report and then link the report into a Teams page and asked one of the users to confirm that they only see the desired client ... they see the entire dataset.**

What could I have missed?

Comment: Have you added the members to the role in the workspace? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-admin-rls#add-members

Comment: Yes. I have edited my original post to make the steps a little clearer.